# My javascript placeholder function(s) only work in IE

Tags: javascript, placeholder

I decided as placeholders are part of HTML5 and not fully supported by the browsers to make my own little placeholder system using Javascript.

This script seems to work perfectly for IE9 but not in Chrome, Safari, Oprea or Firefox.

I'm not sure what the culprit is but for some reason when I click in the field, it drops the cursor in amongst the placeholder text rather than clearing the field and allowing the user to type in a blank field as intended.

Could someone please help me correct this issue?

Chrome is returning the following error messages

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null
- Uncaught TypeError: sting is not a function

The way I code this was that once the form loads the input field 'livesin' it calls my function, then when a user types or the field loses focus it calls the script again.

This is the form field that is using the placeholder system, the span contains my little tick or cross graphics for the form validation.

```
<label>Where do you live<br /> 
    <input id="livesin" onfocus="placeholder()" onblur="placeholder(); addTick('livesin')" maxlength="50" placeholder="e.g. NSW, Australia" />
    <script>placeholder()</script>
</label>

<span id="livesintick" class="neutral"></span>
```

Function  **placeholder** checks to see if the value of the input field is blank, and if so adds my placeholder text and a class to style it, if the field contains my placeholder text I set the value back to being blank and the class to style the user input to look normal once more. After either of these options in then calls another function, explained beneath.

```
function placeholder(){
    if (_("livesin").value == "") {
        _("livesin").className = "placeholderFake";
        _("livesin").value = "e.g. NSW, Australia";
    } else if (_("livesin").value == "e.g. NSW, Australia") {
        _("livesin").className = "placeholderNormal";
        _("livesin").value = "";        
    }

    addTick('livesin')
}
```

**_() Function**

```
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
```

Function **addTick** accecpts any element name passed to it from my form and basically displays a tick graphic next to each form field that isn't empty.

```
function addTick(elem){
    // Specific for livesin field, checking for fake placeholder
    if (_(elem).value == "e.g. NSW, Australia") {
    alert (elem);
        if (_(elem).className == "neutral") {       
            exit;
        }
        _(elem+"tick").className = "neutral";
    }

    if (_(elem).value != "") {
        _(elem+"tick").className = "valid";
    }
}
```

My css is as follows

```
#livesin.placeholderFake {
    color:#808080;
    vertical-align:middle
}
#livesin.placeholderNormal {
    color:#000000;
    vertical-align:middle
}
```

Comment: I would assume most users reading this would be unfamiliar with what library they should assume _() to be. It's not jQuery, as there's no '#' in your selector, and it's (probably) not underscore, as you're directly calling _ as a function, and underscore doesn't typically expect DOM selections. What library are you using for DOM selections?

Comment: _“I decided as placeholders are part of HTML5 and not fully supported by the browsers to make my own […]”_ – that’s the wrong approach; the right one is to use such features in browsers that already support them, and use what is called a “polyfill” to retrofit it in those browsers that don’t support it yet.

Comment: I saw some people had said about using polyfill's but the ones I'd seen when I look at the live demo's didn't seem to work on IE9 which is why I choose to take this route.

You are right I forgot to include the _() so I've amended my code above to include that now.

Comment: Such a script only needs to work in IE. Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox support placeholders natively :-)

Comment: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#web-forms--input-placeholder